# Terraform aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration not using index_document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have an S3 bucket created in Terraform. I based it on the new (post-April 2023) S3 access format suggested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/28353). My bucket declaration looks like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "site" {
  bucket = local.s3_bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "site" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.site,
    aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.site,
  ]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id
  acl    = "public-read"
}
```

The bucket has an `index.html` file in it. However, when I visit the bare S3 bucket URL, I get a `<ListBucketResult>` showing the XML content of the top level of the bucket. Instead, I'm expecting to see the rendered `index.html` file. If I instead point the browser at `$BUCKET_DOMAIN/index.html`, the HTML loads just fine.

Is there a problem with my `aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration` block?

I'm using aws provider version `4.65.0`.

Comment: No problem with the aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration block I think. I've got just like it and it works. Maybe try it without the aws_s3_bucket_acl resource?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't change anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have that object inside of the bucket?

Comment: Have you tried to expose the S3 through a cloudfront?

Comment: Yes, there is an `/index.html` file in the bucket which is world readable. I have never used Cloudfront. Do I have to? This is a page that MAY get 20 visits a week, super low-traffic. It feels totally overkill to put a CDN in front of it…

Comment: I tried destroying and recreating the bucket, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: What you've described sounds like what happens when you access the S3 API endpoints instead of the S3 website endpoints. To get the website-serving behavior you must use the URL exported by the `website_endpoint` attribute of `aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration`. Is that the URL you're using?

Comment: Aaah, yes, this was exactly the problem. Thank you! [More here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html). Please submit an answer and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Martin Atkins for the explanation. S3 has a separate domain for website buckets which you need to use if you want to take advantage of the website configuration options. In my case, I needed to load `http://BUCKET_NAME.s3-website.REGION.amazonaws.com`. More information in [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html).